# What is this C++ struct doing?

Tags: c++

Recently read a book on C++ and it primarily covered classes, and I'm looking at some sample code and am confused by this statement:

```
struct SomeName* SomeOtherName();
```

I know that structs resemble classes in general architecture, so when I see the above, is it in fact referring to a class-like struct or is this a function declaration that is going to return a struct? (Rather, return a pointer to a struct)

Since structs can be like classes or can be simple data structures, seems that the use of the word "structs" in C++ can often lead to a lot of confusion.

Comment: It's returning a pointer to the structure. You don't need that extra `struct` in there in C++.

Comment: C still had the requirement that you had to write `struct struct_name` to refer to the struct type if you didn't use a typedef. For some reason, people sometimes do this in C++ as well although it's completely superfluous there.

Comment: @Cubic I'm not a C++ guy so let me ask it here: does superfluously using the `struct` keyword in C++ count as a bad practice like casting the return value of `malloc()` in C?

Comment: @H2CO3 - No, it doesn't.

Comment: @H2CO3 It's occasionally useful if you are writing a header for a C++ library that's meant to be usable by C and C++, although even then you'd usually stick to the C convention of using `typedef`. If I see a `struct name` style declaration in C++ code I usually remove it.

Comment: @Cubic Thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: If `SomeName` has not been previously declared, you need the `struct`; it's a forward declaration of `SomeName`, as well as a declaration of the function `SomeOtherName`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> or is this a function declaration that is going to return a struct? (Rather, return a pointer to a struct)

Yep, this one.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct SomeName* SomeOtherName();
```

This is a function `SomeOtherName()` returning a pointer `*` to a `struct SomeName`.

See also [How to interpret complex C/C++ declarations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations) or [The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).